# Make sure string is not empty in XML validation with XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, freemarker, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have an `XML` file eg as shown below. I want to make sure that `menonic` exists always and is not empty string.

I set  `use="required"`in my XSD  like  this

`<xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="mnemonic" use="required"/>`
It makes sure that field is present.
But when the string is empty like shown below
`<recipeStructureDef mnemonic="" title="Recipe.Bread">` it passes validation.

Is there any way I can check if the string is not empty string ?

Thanks, Please find the xml and xsd files below.

```
<recipeStructureDef mnemonic="Rice Bag" title="Recipe.Bread">
            <description>           
            </description>

            <parametersTab>
                <parameterTabDef title="Main Parameters">
                    <parameterGroup title="Product Rice">
                    </parameterGroup>
                </parameterTabDef>
             </parametersTab>
</recipeStructureDef>
```

OP needed:

```
  <xs:complexType name="recipeStructureDefType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="description"/>
      <xs:element type="parametersTabType" name="parametersTab"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="mnemonic" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="title"/>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attribute `@mnemonic` must exist:

```
<xs:attribute name="mnemonic" use="required" type="nonEmptyString"/>
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Attribute value for `@mnemonic` must not be empty:

```
<xs:simpleType name="nonEmptyString">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:minLength value="1"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple type xs:string is a plain string with no rules or constraints. You need to create a simple type with some constraints (called 'facets' in XML Schema), and use that simple type in the definition of the mnemonic attribute.

```
    <xs:simpleType name="mnemonicType" >
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:minLength value="1" />
      </xs:restriction>
    <xs:simpleType>

    <xs:complexType name="recipeStructureDefType">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="description"/>
        <xs:element type="parametersTabType" name="parametersTab"/>
      </xs:sequence>

      <xs:attribute type="mnemonicType" name="mnemonic" use="required"/>
      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="title"/>
    </xs:complexType>
```

You may want to specify a minimum length of more than one character, and the minLength facet is one of many that you can use to constrain your simple values. Check out the XML Schema specification for the full list : https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#built-in-primitive-datatypes

Comment: Why post another answer that's essentially the same as an [already existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59887148/290085)?

Comment: Apologies - was delayed while editing my answer, and didn't refresh before posting it.